# How to load svm train data.model by LibSVM in OpenCV 3.1

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem for loading SVM `data.model`in Opencv 3.1 .I look code for loading SVM in train_hog.cpp sample :

```
// Load the trained SVM.
    svm = StatModel::load<SVM>( "my_people_detector.yml" );
    // Set the trained svm to my_hog
    vector< float > hog_detector;
    get_svm_detector( svm, hog_detector );
    my_hog.setSVMDetector( hog_detector );
```

And this is an example my SVM train data.model by using LibSVM :

```
svm_type nu_svc
kernel_type linear
nr_class 2
total_sv 41
rho -0.4447
label 1 -1
nr_sv 21 20
SV
0.06074145976542984 1:0.0516209 2:0.0526671 3:0.0621273 4:0.162602 5:0.252267 6:0.220246 7:0.116933 8:0.0665012 9:0.040535 10:0.0810178 11:0.0799648 12:0.0989393 13:0.204468 14:0.252267 15:0.232619 16:0.10104 17:0.0503855 18:0.0872255 19:0.109535 20:0.135352 21:0.252267 22:0.252267 23:0.252267 24:0.19159 25:0.139957 26:0.0849861 27:0.0621954 28:0.180085 29:0.220934 30:0.252267 31:0.252267 32:0.252267 33:0.14686 34:0.133376 35:0.0798698 36:0.143804 37:0.154667 38:0.175837 39:0.175819 40:0.185156 41:0.242682 42:0.143323 43:0.0656771 
44:0.0752698 45:0.120002 46:0.125042 47:0.137929 48:0.141668 49:0.238362 50:0.242682 51:0.187268 52:0.0587663 53:0.0820198 54:0.0561508 55:0.173739 56:0.235661 57:0.176866 58:0.242682 59:0.242682 60:0.120697 61:0.0926801 62:0.074838 63:0.120294 64:0.099418 65:0.165938 66:0.223667 67:0.242682 68:0.242682
```

So, What I must to do next ?. Until now,  I'm very confusing for understanding load my model data.Which i know `statModel::load<SVM>` load .xml or .yml.Do you have an idea ?

Comment: You can load only models saved with `StatModel::save`

Comment: So, If I want to use my `data.model` for detection use `hog.setsvmdetector()`, What I must to do @Miki ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be to use libsvm inside your OpenCV project, like in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22354047/4966367